# How to serve a Site.com site using HTTPS?

Tags: security, site.com, certificates

We would like to use a custom HTTPS certificate to serve a new site.com site via the HTTPS scheme. How to implement this in Site.com?

I believe the Fall 2014 release added this capability, but I can't find documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented at http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm

From that url:

- From Setup, click Domain Management | Domains.
- Click Add a Domain.
- Enter the Domain Name.
- Add a certificate if you have already set up a CA-signed certificate that supports this domain.
- Click Save.
- Alternatively, click Save & New to add multiple domains.

Comment: So it looks like I have to add (or generate) a cert inside of salesforce first, attach that to the domain, and then it should work for https requests of my site.com site?